# Java FTPFile List with condition

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

I'm retreiving the list of files from an FTP site using the code below using the commons-net:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

private void ExtractFiles(FTPClient ftpClient) {

    ftpPath = "/home/user1/output";
    FTPFile[] ftpFiles = null;

    try {
        ftpFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(ftpPath);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (ftpFiles.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
}
```

My concern is the folder might have hundreds or in the future thousands of files that might cause the process to be slower.  I want to add a condition to only extract the files (*.csv). Is it possible to add a condition in the line:

```
ftpFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(ftpPath, if (*.csv)) ;
```

Something like that? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and there is another listFiles that takes a filter. Here is [the document](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileFilter)).